# How much memory is required to send a 300x500 pixel page to a 500 dpi printer if each pixel is 20 bits?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, interface-design, website-templates, interaction

I am stuck in solving the problem given below:

We are sending a page for printing to a printer with 500 dpi. the page size is 300*500 pixels. if each pixel is 20 bit then how much memory this would take in memory?

If anyone can solve this problem please reply soon. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there and welcome to the site. I have a hard time understanding your question. Maybe you could explain *why* you need to know this? The printer's *dpi* shouldn't really matter in this case. Do you perhaps mean that the resolution of the image is 500 *ppi*? An image with a width of 500 px printed at 500 ppi will only be 1 inch wide. Is that really the case?

Comment: Sir! actually, the question is related to HCI.

Answer (score 1):

(300*500) pixels * 20bit/pixel = 3000000 bits. At 8 bits per byte that is 375 kb. The DPI is, as almost always, a red herring.